# ABCPDF XDoc.AddImageDoc returns current XDoc.Page object id

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, abcpdf

I am using ABCPDF for a project, I have no choice but to use an older version (ABCPDF 7) at this time.

When using `Overridable Function AddImageDoc(doc As Doc, page As Integer, rect As XRect) As Integer` the function is supposed to return the object id of the newly added image object, however when I use it it is returning the current page object id (return value is equal to `XDoc.Page`) I can also confirm that the object id is that of a page by calling `XDoc.GetInfo(id, "Type")` which returns `"page"`.

[image]

Has anyone run into this before, or does anyone have any idea why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to an issue with this version of ABCPDF, it could be present in other versions too. I fixed this issue by upgrading to the latest version (ABCPDF 9).